# nginx, django and url mapping

Tags: django, nginx

The admins where I work have a url http://company.com/app, public facing. They use apache http server. The sysadmins have http://company.com/app pointing to http://internal_ip_address:8080. I have nginx sitting on http://internal_ip:address listening on 8080. I am trying to get nginx to take requests coming into internal_ip_address, route the requests to localhost:9000 which is a django app. Once django is done with the request the resulting page renders with appropriate public facing url (e.g. http://company.com/app . . .) Thanks for any help!

Comment: What are you using to run your django app?

Comment: Gunicorn (socket) and supervisor.

Comment: Well, I have never used gunicorn, have you tried following this page? http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html

Comment: Where I work we use uWSGI and nginx has native support for it, so that makes things a bit easier. But the config in the page I linked is not very complex either.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I basically have my nginx config setup as per those instructions.  And, actually, most things work, except the resulting url when the browser finishes rendering.

Comment: Thanks to all those that tried to help.  After spending a notable amount of time on the issue I determined that it was a http server config issue on a server managed elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all those that tried to help.  After spending a notable amount of time on the issue I determined that it was a http server config issue on a server managed elsewhere.